How to change the key pair of an existing self signed certificate?
I have an existing self signed (root) x.509 certificate.
I need to change its private key (and therefore also the public key, obviously). How to do this?
The new "copy" will not be trusted by anyone at birth, I known I will need to add it to the (development) trust stores.
Alternatively: How to instead generate a new certificate copying all fields from an existing root certificate? (Using it as a template, without having to previously extract manually its fields list.)
Do the main question and the "alternative" wording have the same end result?
